# Get record from same Table with per user limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table of posts in which a user will have multiple posts entered with date, so each user can have different number of posts in the table.

I need to fetch last 10 records from table per user, so say there are 3 users with id, 1,2,3 and each have 12,15,20 posts relatively.

So I need to fetch last 10 posts for each user from the table, my table structure is as follows.

```
id      post_data    created_date           user_id
1       test         2014-01-29 17:49:56    1
2       test         2014-01-28 17:49:56    1
3       test         2014-01-27 17:49:56    1
4       test         2014-01-28 17:49:56    2
5       test         2014-01-29 17:49:56    3
------------
-----------
----------
```

etc.

So can anyone help me out for a query to fetch last 10 records for each user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your query so far? We're not here to solve your homework for you. And I say homework, because this is the kind of question you can expect in the very first chapter of an SQL 101 course.

Comment: We got success for below query so far...which is fetching last 10 records but for only one user...we need such for each user in one query    SELECT * FROM (select * from `z70il_industrynews` where user_id = '761'  order by created_date desc limit 10) q

Comment: Okay, I might have read it a bit wrong, but it seems you're asking 2 different thing. First you're asking for a query that gives the 10 most recent posts for a single user. Then you end your question by saying you need a query that does this for **all** your users at once. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```sql
SELECT id, post_data, created_date, user_id
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, post_data, created_date, user_id,
  (
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
      FROM posts
     WHERE user_id = p.user_id
       AND created_date < p.created_date
  ) rnum
    FROM posts p
) q
 WHERE rnum <= 10
 ORDER BY user_id, created_date DESC;
```

or

```sql
SELECT id, post_data, created_date, user_id
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, post_data, created_date, user_id,
         @n := IF(@u = user_id, @n + 1, 1) rnum, @u := user_id
    FROM posts CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @u := NULL) i
   ORDER BY user_id, created_date DESC
) q
 WHERE rnum <= 10
 ORDER BY user_id, created_date DESC;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c21a/11)** demo

Answer (score 2):

Find the total record of that user and generate offset by subtracting 10 and then can set offset and limit in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a stored procedure and create a cursor to walk through the list of users and fetch last 10 records.